# Custom header is being stripped out

Tags: php, apache, http-headers

I'm passing a custom `X-Authorization` header to my API.

In my API, I'm allowing the header like so:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With, X-Authorization');
```

I'm checking the headers using `print_r(apache_request_headers())`

The only reference to `X-Authorization` in the response is:

```
[access-control-request-headers] => x-authorization
```

I'm using `CGI` which I believe strips regular `Authorization` headers which is why I am trying a custom one.

Answer (score 0):

you will be able to see the request header under the $_SERVER super global, converted the key to uppercase, with prefix HTTP_ & replacing - to _

for example:
X-foo-bar: baz

will be under:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FOO_BAR']
```

The following request:

```
curl -i 0:9000/test.php -H 'X-foo-bar: baz'
```

will return:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: 0:9000
Date: Wed, 27 Jan 2021 21:33:33 GMT
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.24
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

baz
```

PHP (test.php):

```
<?php
echo ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FOO_BAR']);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me when using the curl test. However, using javascript ajax while sender the header always results in it being blank/empty?

Comment: Open the browser's developer tool.
Select in the network tab the request, right click copy as CURL.
what is the curl command?

Comment: It looks like this: curl "https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api_internal/v7/cardinfo.php?misc=yes^&includeAliased=yes^&format=all^&num=2000^&offset=10000" ^
  -H "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*" ^
  -H "Referer: https://ygoprodeck.com/" ^
  -H "X-Authorization: Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0VG9rZW4=" ^
  -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36" ^
  --compressed

Answer (score 0):

The following is working for me on Google Chrome:
HTML file data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>test</title>
<script>
  const test = () => {
  fetch('/3.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    redirect: 'follow',
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Foo': 'bar',
      'X-My-Custom-Header': 'foo-bar-baz',
      'X-Authorization': 'Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0VG9rZW4='
    }),
    body: 'test123'
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      document.querySelector('#response').innerHTML = data['HTTP_X_AUTHORIZATION'];
    });
  };
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="test();">Test</button>
<pre id="response"></pre>
</body></html>
```

Content of 3.php:

```
<?php
header('Conent-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($_SERVER);
```